# Gridview row select and edit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a data entry Form. When I click on the save button I want the data in the form to be saved to the database. I also want a `DataGridview` to be filled from the database.

My question is: when I select any row from a `DataGridview` that row will be shown as selected. Based on primary key data all fields of data entry form will be filled in.

Which event can I use for that? Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Funny, I posted an entire answer to this question yesterday and I could have sworn it was tagged with asp.net and referenced `GridView`.  I wouldn't have seen the question if it wasn't tagged with asp.net...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow[e.RowIndex].ToString();
        }
```

or use the row enter event to get the current row

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //e.RowIndex to get the index of the row
}
```

Comment: I dont want to change records in grid itself. I need to set editable column as false.

Comment: see the changes I have made. is this what you mean in the question?

Comment: I think it should be done by row enter event ... do have any idea regarding that event ? How can I use that ? and getting primary key value from one of the column of gridview and based on that primary key  I can retrive all records from DB

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is by using a binding source and data binding.

So, add a binding source to your form and make this the data source for your `DataGridView` then set up data binding to you data entry fields (here I just bind to a single textbox).

```
// Load your data into a data source - for the example just imagine a data table called dt
bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

// Now we set up a databinding to a text box, to an example property LastName
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", bindingSource1, "LastName", false,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

This binding is automatically two way and works when you select items from the grid. The last name of each item you choose will be shown.

To make the two way binding a little snappier (sometimes it can lag until you enter the grid) you can do the following in the textboxes LostFocus event:

```
void textBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
GridView.RowCommand Event
```

[See for more details - GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx)

Comment: I am asking about windows form not web form

Answer (score 0):

when you select a row SelectedIndexChanging is called

when a row is selected SelectedIndexChanged is called

for filling the gridview you have to use RowDataBound

For complete list see the following msdn link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx

Comment: Hi I am talking about windows form not web form.These events are used for web form